# How to convert a datestring to date object without timezone

Tags: javascript, date, jsonserializer

I want to convert a date string '03/08/2016' to date object without a timezone.

```
convertToDateFormat(Datestr) {
    if ( Datestr!="" ) { // Datestr="03/08/2016"
        var datedata = Datestr.split("/");
        let year=datedata[2];
        let month=(parseFloat(datedata[1]) - 1);
        let day=datedata[0];
        var formatedDate = new Date( month + '-' + day + '-' + year);
        var formatedDatestring=JSON.stringify(formatedDate);
    }
}
```

Here I got the formatedDate as a Date object as

> Wed Aug 03 2016 15:20:58 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

and stringify it I got the formatedDatestring as

> "2016-08-02T18:30:00.000Z"

**But I want the formatedDatestring as "2016-08-03T00:00:00.000Z"**

Comment: Change the last line to `var formatedDatestring=JSON.stringify(formatedDate).split("T")[0] + "T00:00:00.000Z";`

Comment: You should use dateformatter

Comment: thanks but it only replaces the "T18:30:00.000Z" with "T00:00:00.000Z". I got a day before the selected date. @Archer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overcomplicating

```
function convertToDateFormat(Datestr) {
    if ( Datestr!="" ) { // Datestr="03/08/2016"
        var datedata = Datestr.split("/");
        var formatedDateString=datedata[2]+'-' + datedata[1] + '-' + datedata[0] + 'T00:00:00.000Z';
        return formatedDateString;
    }
}
console.log(convertToDateFormat("03/08/2016")) // 2016-08-03T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Thanks a lott... :)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my way for doing your idea.**

```
const getDateNoTz = (strDate) => strDate ? strDate.split('/').reverse().join('-') + 'T00:00:00.000Z': '';
let myDate = getDateNoTz('30/09/2019');
```